# Initialising in Python using Keyword Args without sharing between instances

Tags: python, initialization, keyword-argument

How can I use keyword args in an initialiser without sharing it between instances of a class?

Example of the bad behaviour below, if I were to add anything to the set `foo` then it would be added in both instances.

```
In [1]: class Klass:
    def __init__(self, foo=set()):
        self.foo = foo
In [2]: a = Klass()
In [3]: b = Klass()
In [4]: a.foo is b.foo
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this issue will **only** occur with *mutable default arguments* - see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761). To use a mutable default argument, it is conventional to set the default to `None` in the function definition, then check inside the function whether or not a value has been supplied:

```
class Klass:

    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        if foo is None:
            foo = set()
        self.foo = foo
```

or:

```
self.foo = foo if foo is not None else set()
```

Note that `None` is tested by identity (`if foo is None:`), not equality (`if foo == None:`) or truthiness (`if not foo:`). For example, the latter is an issue if you want to explicitly pass in an empty set you have referenced elsewere.

Comment: Is there a stylistic reason to not inline the `foo = set()` with the `if`?

Comment: @BookOfGreg per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), *"Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged."*, although it subsequently adds *"...sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on the same line"*