# Python: when adding an object to a list, it copies a dict attribute to the rest of the objects in the list

Tags: python, list, oop, dictionary, arguments

I have this class `Knop` (meaning 'button') with the following constructor:

```
def __init__(self, rechthoek, kleur = BUTTONCOLOR, actie = printtest, tekst = "", tekstkleur = BUTTONTEXTCOLOR, actie_args = {}, score = -1 ):

    self.rechthoek = rechthoek # pygame.Rect object
    self.kleur = kleur # button color: (r,g,b) tuple
    self.actie = actie # the function to call when pressing the button
    self.actie_args = actie_args # the arguments to the function actie
    self.tekst = tekst # the text in the button
    self.tekstkleur = tekstkleur # the color of the text
    self.score = score
```

The idea is that the function `actie` is called with the arguments `actie_args` (which is a dict) as follows: `return_val = self.actie(**self.actie_args)`.

Now, somewhere else, I make a list `knoppen` (meaning 'buttons') by creating new instances:

```
knoppen = []
for i, emotie in enumerate(emoties):
    ypos = y[4] + FONTSIZE*i*2 - FONTSIZE/4
    r = pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, buttonwidth, buttonheight)
    eknop = Knop(r, emo_kleur[i], tekst = emoties[i])
    eknop.actie = set_emotie
    eknop.tekstkleur = BLACK
    knoppen.append(eknop)
```

And a little later on in the program:

```
cnt_rect = pygame.Rect(x[1], y[8], x[3], y[1])
bknop = Knop(cnt_rect, BUTTONCOLOR, tekst = TXT_CONFIRM)
bknop.actie = bevestig
bknop.actie_args["annfile"] = appvars["saved_utterances"]
bknop.actie_args["utt_i_file"] = appvars["gebleven_bij_utterance"]
knoppen.append(bknop)
```

Now, when these latter block is executed, a problem arises. The `actie_args` argument of `bknop` seems to be 'copied' to the `actie_args` of all the other buttons created before. I tested this by making a `__str__` function within the `Knop` class and printing an `eknop` before and after creating the `bknop`.

What is this caused by and how can I solve this?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the duplicate @jonrsharpe, but I find it hard to apply that to my situation. Is there anything I can do to make it work as I want to?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28677657/3001761